# Overload `unsigned` specifier for classes

Tags: c++

I'm trying to define my own datatype (called `sfloat`) that's similar to a float, but uses a different number of mantissa bits and exponential bits to better suit my data range and precision. The goal is to define a new datatype that can replace the float in already existing applications. Everything's working out so far, except that I have been unable to override or define the `unsigned` operator such that

```
unsigned sfloat(3.141527)
```

would return the unsigned version of this class, `usfloat(3.141527)`.

It seems like the `unsigned` specifier *might* be able to be overloaded since VS intellisense is not complaining in the header file:

```
sfloat::sfloat(float f) { m_data = get16bit(f); }
operator unsigned() { /*Do stuff here */ };
```

But it's not working in declaration and initialization:

```
unsigned sfloat myPi= 3.141527; // Error: expected a ';'
```

I don't even know if this is possible to do in C++, and I'm curious if anybody has done this before?

Comment: `unsigned` is not a qualifier like `const` or `volatile`. It is an inseparable part of a type name, like `short` or `long`.

`unsigned` by itself is a synonym for `unsigned int`, so `operator unsigned()` is just an operator to cast to `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to C++ default-int for signedness, `operator unsigned ()` is just a syntactic shorthand for `operator unsigned int ()`. User-defined types cannot be declared `signed` or `unsigned`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct way to accomplish what you're trying to do.  As @Angew mentioned in his answer, `unsigned` cannot be applied to user-defined types.

On the other hand, you could fake this up by defining types named `sfloat` and `unsigned_sfloat` which had conversions defined between them.  You could then write

```
unsigned_sfloat x(137.0f); // Close enough. ^_^
```

And then define a conversion operator as

```
operator unsigned_sfloat() {
    ... implementation here ...
}
```

This gives you something syntactically close to what you want and works around the fact that the language does not let you use the `unsigned` keyword to modify a custom type.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You could mock something like this up with templates:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T = int>
class myfloat
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value, "myfloat should only be instantiated on \"signed\" and \"unsigned\" ints");

    const bool isSigned = true;

    // the rest of the signed implementation  
};

template <>
class myfloat<unsigned>
{
    const bool isSigned = false;

    // the rest of the unsigned implementation  
};

int main()
{
    myfloat<> a;           // signed  
    myfloat<signed> b;     // signed  
    myfloat<unsigned> c;   // unsigned  

    // myfloat<float> d; // <-- compile error

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this just *detect* whether the float is unsigned, rather than giving a way of modifying the class to be signed or unsigned?

Comment: @templatetypedef Due to the specialization, you can have completely different implementations of the signed and unsigned versions (if you desired). You could also pull out common functionality, of course.

Comment: @jerry- Ah, never mind.  You edited the post to mention that the specializations also include the complete body of the implementations.  At the time I posted the comment, you just had the `isSigned` constant in the specializations.

Comment: @templatetypedef Yes, the comments previously just said `// signed implementation` and `// unsigned implementation`, your comment prompted me to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
template<typename T>
struct Unsigned;
```

and use it like:

```
Unsigned<sfloat> usfloat
```

Now, you have to specialize `Unsigned` for your type `Float`, but this should communicate "is an unsigned version of `Float`" slightly better than an `unsigned_sfloat` type.  I'd only bother with this if you where building an entire library of such types you might want to attach `Unsigned<>` to, however.